# Are high-frequency gravitational waves inherently stronger/higher energy? Like the way gamma photons have more energy than radio photons?

Tags: gravity, cosmology

A simple yes or no would be helpful, but a brief explanation would be nice too.....

What about sound waves?

Comment: It is worth emphasizing that classically it is only amplitude and not frequency that determines the energy density of electromagnetic waves. The relationship with frequency enters with quantum mechnaics (and can be reconciled with the classical behavior in terms of wave-packets--a narrow band wave packet has higher amplitude at higher frequency...). To expect a frequency dependency for gravitational waves one would need to examine *them* in a quatum framework.

Answer (score 3):

A graviton would have energy $\hbar \omega$, so indeed would have larger energy for larger frequency, like photons. This is just a feature of quantum mechanics, and is not “special” to any particular kind of particle.

Of course, gravitons have never been observed. There is even work by Freeman Dyson and others that it may be fundamentally impossible to ever observe a single graviton. For example, if you tried to build a version of LIGO sensitive enough to see a graviton, the detector would need to pack so much energy into a small space that it would collapse into a black hole.

For a classical gravitational wave (just like for light), there is nothing intrinsically more energetic about a wave with higher frequency. The energy is proportional to a combination of the frequency and amplitude of the wave.

The same basic story is true for sound waves. Quanta of waves in a medium (phonons) have energy $\hbar\omega$ just like any other quanta. For classical sound waves the energy is a combination of amplitude and frequency. The only difference is that phonons have been observed, and there isn’t as much of a risk of collapsing into a black hole

Comment: *"The energy is proportional to a combination of the frequency and amplitude of the wave."* There is no frequency dependence *at all* in the purely classical framework. You can construct a ferequency dependnce by building wavepackets, which is how you connect the classical and quantum behaviors.

Comment: @dmckee If I have a classical plane wave, $f(x,t)=A e^{i\omega (t-\hat{k}\cdot\vec{x}/c}$, then the energy $E\propto |\partial_t f|^2 + |(\nabla f)|^2 \propto A^2 \omega^2$. A physical example would be creating waves on a string with the same amplitude and different frequencies will result in different energies. Depending on exactly what you want to hold fixed, the frequency dependence could of course be different; the Larmour formula says the power of proportional to $\omega^4$ in part because the amplitude depends on the acceleration of the charge. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Agreed, however, that the best way to connect classical and quantum descriptions is to look at the energy in a a coherent state.

Comment: Quantum mechanically, a single particle has energy $\hbar\omega$. In classical mechanics, the energy is a combination of amplitude and frequency, which depends on your problem and what is being held fixed. In electromagnetism, if you think of the amplitude as being the electric field, then the energy doesn’t depend on frequency. However if you want to tie the field back to the source that generated it, you may find the field depends on the frequency of oscillation of a point charge. What everyone will agree on is that $\hbar \omega$ has no particular meaning in classical mechanics.